# Python-bottle server receives no requests despite inactive firewall

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, python

I’m working on a recently created remote DigitalOcean Ubuntu Droplet. There are no cloud firewalls, and I’ve disabled the server firewall with the following command:

`sudo ufw disable`

When I use the simple python server `python3 -m http.server` to serve directory contents, I am able to view them by visiting `http://XXX.XX.XXX.XX:8000/` in my browser, although there can be a long lag. However, my browser returns an “unable to connect to server” message when I run the following Python-bottle server:

```
from bottle import route, run
  
@route('/')
def hello():
    return "Today is a beautiful day"

run(host='localhost', port=8000, debug=True)
```

From the server side, the running Python-bottle server does not seem to receive any of the requests that I make from my browser.

**QUESTION:** Why isn’t my Python script receiving inbound traffic? Why does the simple Python server receive my requests, while the Python-bottle server does not? Is there some other firewall that I haven’t dealt with?

Comment: Probably because you restricted connections to localhost. See the documentation for your app framework. We can't handle programming questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MichaelHampton has answered your question: you've told your server to only listen on the `localhost` address, so of course you can't connect to it from anywhere else. Try changing that to `0.0.0.0`, which means "all addresses":

```
from bottle import route, run
  
@route('/')
def hello():
    return "Today is a beautiful day"

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True)
```